# How to hide Google Charts hours from hAxis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Im using line chart from Google Charts. I show date on hAxis (horizontal). My major gridlines show date normally. But there are time labels between date labels. And i dont want time labels. 
[image]
I tried to put that property in hAxis on chart options but nothing changed

`minorGridlines:{textPosition: 'none' }`

hAxis options;

```
hAxis: {titleTextStyle: {color: '#0000ff'},
            slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:60,format: 'd/M/yy',minorGridlines:{textPosition: 'none' },gridlines: {
              count: -1,
              units: {
                days: {format: ['d.MM']},
                hours: {format: ['HH:mm']},
              }
             }
},
```

is there anyone who knows the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, remove the options for `gridlines`.
however, this could cause the same date labels to repeat.
to prevent from repeating,
you can provide your own `ticks`.

the `hAxis.ticks` option takes an array, in this case, of dates.
to build the `ticks` array, we can use data table method --> `getColumnRange(colIndex)`
this will return the `min` & `max` values of the column.

then we can to build our `ticks` array.

```
// build hAxis ticks
var hAxisTicks = [];
var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
var oneDay = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i <= dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
  hAxisTicks.push(new Date(i));
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2019, 0, 1, 0), 10],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 1, 6), 20],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 1, 12), 30],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 1, 18), 40],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 2, 0), 10],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 2, 6), 20],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 2, 12), 30],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 2, 18), 40],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 3, 0), 10],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 3, 6), 20],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 3, 12), 30],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 3, 18), 40],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 4, 0), 10],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 4, 6), 20],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 4, 12), 30],
    [new Date(2019, 0, 4, 18), 40],
  ]);

  // build hAxis ticks
  var hAxisTicks = [];
  var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  var oneDay = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i <= dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
    hAxisTicks.push(new Date(i));
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'd/M/yy',
      ticks: hAxisTicks
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

building the ticks manually will cause a performance hit,
but only by a couple milliseconds, which is nothing.

see following working snippet,
540 rows are drawn, the milliseconds it takes to build the ticks are shown in the console...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');

  for (var i = (new Date(2019, 0, 1)).getTime(); i <= (new Date(2019, 3, 1)).getTime(); i = i + (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
    data.addRow([new Date(i), i]);
  }

  // build hAxis ticks
  var test = new Date();
  console.log('rows', data.getNumberOfRows());
  var hAxisTicks = [];
  var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  var oneDay = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i <= dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
    hAxisTicks.push(new Date(i));
  }
  console.log('milliseconds', ((new Date()).getTime() - test.getTime()));

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'd/M/yy',
      ticks: hAxisTicks
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have a question about this solution. Does this solution reduce the performance when there is too much data? I get 280 data per day for now.

Comment: i decide to keep hours. but i accept that as an answer. when i delete gridlines:{...} from options hours deleted. Thank you for your support.